# Using passwordStrengthRegularExpression vs. a testable function?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, passwords

Re: authentication in an ASP.Net application, are there any benefits of using the membership providers attribute [passwordStrengthRegularExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.passwordstrengthregularexpression%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) instead of writing my own validation function (which of course would use the same regex) but which I can run unit tests against?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage to `passwordStrengthRegularExpression` is that's it is built in and as such very easy to use and change on the fly.

If you need to update/change the regular expression, you only need to change the configuration and restart the application.

Unless you write your code to do the same (pick up the regular expression from configuration, or inject it in some other way), you will be hardcoding it, meaning a recompile and redeploy of your application.